# What will happen to response if the sender actor is already gone?

Tags: c++, c++-actor-framework

Consider the following example. A `hello_world actor` sends a "hello" string to `mirror actor`, then it terminates immediately. What will happen to the response `world` returned from `mirror actor`? Ignored? Left in `hello_world actor` mailbox? Could the mirror know its response is lost?

```
behavior mirror(event_based_actor* self)
{
    return { [=](std::string s){ return "world"; } };
}
void hello_world(event_based_actor* self, const actor& theMirror)
{
    self->send(theMirror, "hello");
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Consider the following example. A hello_world actor sends a "hello" string to mirror actor, then it terminates immediately. What will happen to the response world returned from mirror actor? Ignored? Left in hello_world actor mailbox?

Assume that `hello_world` has already terminated. When the CAF runtime transfers control into `mirror` for the next time, the statement `return "world"` would attempt to send a reply to the sender. Since the sender no longer exists, the runtime simply discards the message.

> Could the `mirror` know its response is lost?

**TL;DR**: you have to implement your own acknowledgement protocol on top if you need message delivery guarantees.

**Long answer**: by *monitoring* an actor, you can hook its termination. Ultimately this just enqueues a specific system message in the monitoring actor's mailbox. Assuming a single-hop scenario where no message-reordering can take place, `hello_world` will send a message, terminate, and then the runtime will send a DOWN message to all actors that monitored `hello_world`. `mirror`'s mailbox then contains first the string and then the DOWN message. This means `mirror` can only detect a failure after it attempted to send the message.

There is one exception: if you spawn `mirror` as a *priority-aware* actor, it can process messages based on their priority. Think about it as two separate mailboxes per actor. All system messages in CAF have high priority, which means that there exists a scenario where you *might* be able to detect failure before replying, but only when the runtime transfers control into `mirror` after *both* messages already exist in `mirror`'s mailbox. If the DOWN message gets delayed and the runtime transfers control into `mirror` with just the string message sitting in the mailbox, then you `mirror` can't detect failure either.

That said, actors can fail at any time and the runtime can only provide near-real time fault propagation. Therefore, your design must be resilient to such failure, which means you must roll your own acknowledgement mechanism for reliable message delivery.

Comment: To add a bit more detail to this answer: When using `sync_send` (which will be replaced by `request` in CAF 0.15), the runtime generates error messages if the *receiver* no longer exists. However, this does not implement a three-way handshake, i.e., `hello_world` can detect whether `mirror` does correctly respond, but `mirror` is not able to track what happens with the response message (unless you implement this on top, as @mavam already stated).